# ExpandableListView. Expand and go to specific group

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

How could I expand a specific group of ExpandableListView  AND goto this group?

I tried this:

```
ExpandableListView mListView;
mListView.expandGroup(13);
```

it expands group number 13. But it is out of screen.. I would like to goto this group directly, so that it appears at the top of the screen.  Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the xml for expandable listview,

```
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
android:transcriptMode="disabled"
```

and then use

```
setSelectedPositionFromTop(int, int)
```